# What is a kernel (with regards to dependency injection)?

Tags: dependency-injection, terminology

I see the term kernel used a lot but I am not sure what it means. Can you give an example.

Comment: It might be a good idea to quote some phrase or sentence that uses "kernel" in the way that confuses you.

Comment: There are endless resources on the web on this topic; did you search?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(computing)

Comment: @jeffamaphone, I'm pretty sure that's not the kind of kernel to which he refers.

Answer (score 2):

The kernel is the container itself. It's called "kernel" in Windsor (actually [MicroKernel](http://github.com/castleproject/Castle.InversionOfControl/blob/master/src/Castle.Windsor/MicroKernel/DefaultKernel.cs))  and Ninject because it only provides the core injection functionality, relying on wrappers (in the case of MicroKernel, it's [WindsorContainer](http://github.com/castleproject/Castle.InversionOfControl/blob/master/src/Castle.Windsor/Windsor/WindsorContainer.cs)) or modules/extension methods (in the case of Ninject) to provide convenience features (for example, WindsorContainer provides XML configuration parsing)

Answer (score 2):

The *kernel* in Ninject and other dependency injectors is the core of the application. It's a container for the other modules.

A *module* represents an independent section of your application. You're free to organise them as you see fit within the structure of your codebase.  You then load these modules into the kernel through the constructor. [See this page](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Modules-and-the-Kernel) for an example of that.

The kernel object is also the object responsible for resolving dependencies and creating new objects.

For example in Ninject in C#/.NET you can use the kernel to bind an interface to its implememtation:

```
IKernel ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
ninjectKernel.Bind<IMyFoo>().To<MyFoo>();
```

Then when you create an object as follows...

```
IMyFoo myFoo = ninjectKernel.Get<IMyFoo>;
```

... the kernel will automatically return an instance of type `MyFoo` because of the binding you just specified.

[This page](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Modules-and-the-Kernel) gives more of an overview of how kernels and modules fit together, for further reading. [This page](https://ninject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Modules%20and%20the%20Kernel) from Ninject may also help.